# CHSH Bell measurement, why is there difference between 45 and 135 degree?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-optics

Let assume BBO type-2 that simultaneously generates entangled photon pair in forms of horizontal polarization (H) and vertical polarization (V) of photon. One photon is going to Alice and the other is going to Bob. Alice and Bob could measure either H-photon or V-photon. When Alice receive H-photon, then Bob definitely receive V-photon due to relation of photon pair. And, there are polarizer in front of both Alice and bob detector so that only certain polarization states are transmitted.

If the polarizer is set to 45 or 135 degrees, H-photon and V-photon are detected at half the amount, respectively. In general, the following characteristics can be found by looking at the experimental results.

case 1:
Alice's polarizer : 45 degree,
Bob's polarizer : 45 degree.
The coincidence count is maximum.

case 2:
Alice's polarizer : 45 degree,
Bob's polarizer : 135 degree.
The coincidence count is zero(minimum).

or vice versa.

Q: Why are case 1 and case 2 different?
A 45 or 135 degree polarizer is considered to be the same phenomenon that transmits half of H-photon and V-photon, so I don't think they should be different.

Comment: Are you sure they are different?  If I understand what you’re saying then all photons whether they’re vertical or horizontal would hit the polarizer at 45°

Comment: Yes, they are different, resulting in a violation of Bell's inequality. I'm asking because it's hard to understand in my common sense. http://cems.irb.hr/en/ij/pqo/quantum-entanglement-of-photons-and-bell-theorem-test-at-cems/

Comment: Your video is different than your question. In your question you are specifically sending vertical or horizontal polarized photons through polarizers that are always set to 45 degrees. In the video Bob takes readings from all 360 degrees. When a vertically polarized photon reaches a 45 degree polarizer, there is a 50/50 chance it will make it through. When a horizontally polarized photon reaches a 45 degree polarizer there is a 50/50 chance of making it through.  135 or 45 degrees are the same with either one always being 45 degrees from the photons polarization.

Comment: My question for case 1 and 2 is in there link graph (http://cems.irb.hr/en/ij/pqo/quantum-entanglement-of-photons-and-bell-theorem-test-at-cems/).

Answer (score 1):

You have stated case #1 incorrectly. Alice's 45 degree polarizer (in this case Anti-Diagonal) is not the same as Bob's 45 degree polarizer (in this case Diagonal). The two polarizers are perpendicular or opposite to each other. Therefore when a photon pair are ANTI-CORRELATED the coincidences should be at maximum because when one photon lines up with an analyzer then the other photon will also line up.
In case #2 Alice's analyzer is again set to 45 degree Anti-Diagonal but now Bob's analyzer is set to 135 degrees, If you visualize this you will see that 135 degrees is the same as 45 degree Anti-Diagonal. This is different than case #1 because now the two analyzers are set exactly the same instead of opposite. Now when you send a pair of ANTI-CORRELATED photons, the coincidences will be minimum because when one photon lines up with an analyzer the other photon will be completely blocked.

Comment: H-photon or V-photon goes to Alice and Bob at random. Whether the polarizer is Anti-Diagonal or Diagonal, the amount of H-photon or V-photon is the same, only half the amount can be transmitted. It should be the same, but is it a mystery because it's different? Is this quantum mechanics?

Comment: If you only have V and H photons interacting with diagonal and anti-diagonal polarizers then of course only half will be transmitted. The link  (cems.irb.hr/en/ij/pqo/…) describes the experiment different than that. It shows Max coincidence when Alice (Anti-Diagonal) compares to Bob (Diagonal). It also shows  Min coincidence when Alice (Anti-Diagonal) compares to Bob 135 degree (which is also Anti-Diagonal). As you can see neither of these are V on diagonal or H on diagonal.